# How could I configure the MSSQLLocal default datetime format

Tags: c#, sql, ado

I am writing a program to interact with MSSQLLocal DB using C# through winforms but I find a problem witht the default datetime, it is not the date time format we use in my countr, I wonder how could I through Sql client -sql default C# classes I could change the default date format for a database or All the existing databases?

this could let me to format the datetime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

but this doesnt change the default dateformat, how can i change programatically the DB datetime default format?

some code example

```
var connectionstr = $@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog={DBname};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
                var con = new SqlConnection(connectionstr);
                con.Open();

                string changeDate = $@"SET DATEFORMAT dmy;";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(changeDate , con);
                var res = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertCmd, con);

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter() { InsertCommand = cmd };

                adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


                adapter.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                command.Dispose();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your dates and datetimes should becoming into C# as `DateTime` objects, which (when converted to a string via `.ToString()`) are converted to string using the thread culture. I'm not sure what culture is used for the debugger display - I would assume the one Visual Studio is running under.

Comment: A DateTime has no format. When you create a field of type DateTime on your database you don't store there a string formatted in some way. You store a DateTime value (internally some kind of a number) Then it is up to you or to your database tool to show that number in some formatted way as a string

Comment: In winforms, you can choose to format the DateTime objects to any format you wish.

Comment: Dates have no format, either in .NET or SQL Server, they are binary values. Formatting applies *only* when displaying that binary value, or parsing a string to create a DateTime value.

Comment: `the date time format we use in my country` - you probably don't have to do *anything*.  Desktop applications already format dates and numbers using the end user's locale. The *same* `datetime` value will appear as `6/2/2020` in a European country and `2/6/2020` in the US. ASP.NET tries to detect the browser's preferred language, although the application can override this and use eg the user's preferred language. That's how most forums work

Comment: All you need is to use IFormatProvider when you are converting it to string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well I checked my OS is set to my region but the local setting arent applied to SQL

Comment: @PontiacGTX *there's no such thing as a date format*. They are binary values, period. Changing the locale changes how the dates are displayed on desktop applications. You *don't* have to change anything in the database, provided you use date types of course

Comment: @PontiacGTX the *real* question is how and where do you display the dates? That's what needs to change

Comment: this allows to do what I need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please attach some code to your question so that we can see where you are going wrong with this.

Comment: @John added an example

Comment: Now the question is, what is the content of `InsertCmd`? You don't seem to be using SQL parameters, which is likely responsible for the problem you're seeing. Parse the user's date/time string into a .NET `DateTime`, and pass it as a query parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out before adding a new value to the row you would need to include in the string CAST(01/01/2020) as dateformat

Answer (score 0):

The datetime object in the database is just a datetime, the data can be set to a certain format when displaying in WinForm if you require it. For example, if i wanted the datetime to be display in the UK format:

```
    DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

[Datetime Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("d")` will also produce the same result, provided the thread is running in the en-gb culture. If the user's machine is configured for English (UK) then the thread will be en-gb by default. [This comment is mostly for OP]

Comment: @Neil Norris, the thing is I want to set the default datetime format on MSSQLLocal database to my country's date format, it is using the default sql datetime  which doesnt match my OS's selected region

Comment: Ah that makes sense. have you tried: ALTER LOGIN your_login WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=British

Comment: @NeilNorris i think this fits more what i need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-useroptions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @NeilNorris well tried the code in the link but doesnt work, check the OP for the current C# code

Comment: You can't programmatically change how SQL stores datetimes, it is stored as a datetime in the database - that is standard. How you display it in your program is what you can actually change, so when you use the data in a WinForm or ASP page, you set the format of how you want it to display it.